# Prove that $\sqrt{12 x^3-3}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

First, I thought that it should be easy to prove that $\sqrt{12  x^3-3}$ for $x\neq1$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}^+$ is irrational, but I am stuck!

I am almost sure that this is irrational, because if it is not, then some theorems are wrong and it is very improbable.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: set $$\sqrt{12x^3-3}=\frac{m}{n}$$ with $$\gcd(m,n)=1$$

Comment: I started like this, but I have no idea how to progress. Any help?

Comment: square both sides and solve this for $x^3$

Comment: Right. Then it is $x=(m^2/(12n^2)+1/4)^{1/3}$ which is still not clear why should be irrational.

Comment: Please, what theorems are wrong if the statement isn't true?

Comment: your radicand is rational and no cubic number

Comment: $y^2=12x^3-3$ is an elliptic curve with rational point $(1,3)$. The rational points on an elliptic curve form a group, so I'd see what $(1,3)+(1,3)$ is (where the addition is the operation on the curve). The way to do this is to find the tangent to the curve at $(1,3)$ and see where else it meets the curve.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson. This gives me something to think about.

Comment: If some theorems wrong if it is rational, then use contradiction to prove your statement.

Comment: Alternatively, if you multiply through by 144, you get $Y^2=X^3-432$, where $Y=12y$ and $X=12x$. This is an example of a *Mordell curve*, and solutions to those have been tabulated and can be found online by searching for that term.

Comment: The idea of @GerryMyerson should show the statement is true.  That elliptic curve has analytic rank 0, and the only $\Bbb{Q}$-rational points are a cyclic group of order $3$ generated by $P=[12,36]$.

Comment: Yeah, the tangent of the curve $y^2=12x^3-3$ has triple contact at $(1,3)$. The slope is $y'=36x^2/2y=6$, so the tangent has equation $y=6x-3$, but
$$12x^3-3-(6x-3)^2=12(x-1)^3.$$

Comment: Suppose $$q=12 x^3-1$$ and $$x=t+1$$ . We have:
$$ q= 3(4 t^3 +12 t^2 + 12 t +3)$$. Suppose $$t = 3 k$$ so that:
$$q=3^2 (36 k^3 +36 k^2 + 12 k +1)$$
I think you can easily prove that polynomial $$36 k^3 +36 k^2 + 12 k +1$$ can not be perfect square and thereby q^ (0.5) can not be rational.

Comment: $x = p/q$

$$\sqrt {12x^3 - 3} = y$$
$$\implies 12x^3 = y^2 + 3$$
$$\because \text{$12x^3$ is even, $y^2$ is odd hence $y$ is also odd or $\sqrt {\text{odd}}$}$$
$$\because 12 = 4 \cdot 3x^3, 4 \times 3x^3 = y^2 + 3$$
$$\implies 4x^3 = 1 + y^2/3$$

Making $\sqrt 2$ as the subject, we'll be expressing it as a fraction. With $x^{3/4}$ as the denominator such that $x \in \mathbb{Q}^+ \neq 1$ then there are values for $x$ such that $x^{3/4} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (e.g. $16^3 = 8^4$) which obviously can't happen because $\sqrt 2 \neq \frac{p}{q}$.

$$\therefore x = \frac{p}{q} : q \neq 1$$

Comment: @George, you lost me at "making $\sqrt2$ as the subject".

Comment: @sirous, what about when $k=0$?

Comment: @Dr., I can't see where you're going with that argument.

Comment: @George $x,y$ are rationals, but you seem to be assuming that they are integers (e.g. in parity arguments). Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4990/how-could-i-calculate-the-rank-of-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x3-432

Comment: Many great hints and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.- You are stuck because your problem is intrinsically difficult. This involves to find the rational points of the elliptic curve $$y^2=12x^3-3$$ You have the obvious point $(x,y)=(1,3)$ which **if not of torsion** will give infinitely many other rational points in which case the rank of the curve is at least equal to $1$. To see if this is verified we do not need the formulas of adding the group defined by the curve but simply using the old Bachet's method of chords and tangents from which  the group law of elliptic curves comes.

The derivative $y'=\dfrac{18x^2}{\sqrt{12x^3-3}}$ at the point $(1,3)$ is $y'(1)=6$ and the tangent at $(1,3)$ is $y=3(2x-1)$. This tangent cuts the curve at another point given by the system

$$\begin{cases}y=3(2x-1)\\y^2=12x^3-3\end{cases}$$ If this "another" point is distinct of $(1,3)$ we will properly speaking get another point with possibilities of infinitely (not necessarily)  many other points.

The resultant of the system is $$x^3-3x^2+3x-1=(x-1)^3=0$$

Thus $(x,y)=(1,3)$ is a torsion point of the elliptic curve $y^2=12x^3-3$ and the rank of it could be  $0$ if does not exist another rational point not of torsion. It seems that in fact the rank is $0$ but, I repeat, this is a difficult, non-elementary problem.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** $\,\ y^2+3 = 12x^3\,\Rightarrow\, \overbrace{(3+y)^{\large\color{#c00}3}+(3-y)^{\large\color{#c00}3}}^{\Large 18(y^2+3)} = (6x)^{\large\color{#c00}3}\Rightarrow\, y=\pm3, x=1\,$ by $\rm{FLT}_{\large\color{#c00}3}$

---

**Remark** $ $ More generally we can completely classify the the points of the Fermat cubic over real quadratic fields using the following result.

**Theorem** $ $ Solutions of $\,x^3+y^3= 1\,$ over $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)\,$ are in correspondence with the $\,\Bbb Q\,$-points on the elliptic curve  $\,y^2 = x^3 - 432\, d^3$

An elementary proof: Lemma $2.1$ in F. Jarvis and Paul Meekin, [The Fermat equation over $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2).$](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/maths/jarvismeekin08-fermat-jnt3079.pdf)

Comment: Perfect. Very Interesting!

Comment: A nice reduction to a "widely known" Diophantine equation:-)

Comment: This is a nice solution. Great!